# Storing Data on Non-Activity classes

Tags: android

I would like to determine if this is bad practice, since I have implemented this in some locations.

I have two activities, MainActivity and SecondActivity.

If I want to transfer the string "Hello" from Main to Second, I use a class called Transfer. In this class I have a static String that I set to "Hello", which I access from the onResume method of SecondActivity.

How does android manage the "Transfer" class? Is it tied to MainActivity and destroyed along with it? Is there any other behavior I should be aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static members exist as long as the app is in the memory.

This approach works fine. Another way to share data between two activities is to make use of [`putExtra`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle%29) to put data into second activity and [`getExtras`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getExtras%28%29) to get the data.

Answer (score 2):

Given that the String field is static, I'd say is bounded to the whole process and not to the MainActivity.

The problem is, the android os might free your app's resources to start another process.
What may happen is that your app gets backgrounded, the os needs it resources and frees the memory, and then the user gets back to SecondActivity. The process gets recreated and the previously initialized static field is now null.

If your need is to pass Strings between activities, I would bundle them into the intent's extras.